# CONCAT & CASE WHEN combined

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concatenation, case

I'm trying to create a query that concatenates the directions field that were involved in each transaction_id.

I've tried to do it by creating a flag table with multiple case whens, and then querying on it, but as you can see in the image below, I'm having trouble to get a multiple 1's flag in one single row ID.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Here are the code and the tables I'm using:

```
SELECT 
    t2.trans_id
    CASE WHEN t2.dept_nbr IN (SELECT dept_nbr FROM t3 with WHERE dir = 'dir1')  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flag_dir1,
    CASE WHEN t2.dept_nbr IN (SELECT dept_nbr FROM t3 with WHERE dir = 'dir2')  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flag_dir2
FROM 
    t2
```

[image: Tables and desired result]

Answer (score 1):

This should put the output in format required.  The 'trans_id' and 'dir' columns are `GROUP BY` summarized and the maximum dept_nbr ('max_dept_nbr') is selected.  Then for each 'trans_id' the unique 'dir' values are string aggregated (with '-' as separator) and ordered (within grouping) by the max_dept_nbr.

```
with dir_cte(trans_id, dir, max_dept_nbr) as (
    select t2.trans_id, t3.dir, max(t3.dept_nbr)
    from t2
         join t3 ON t2.dept_nbr = t3.dept_nbr
    group by t2.trans_id, t3.dir)
select trans_id, string_agg(dir, '-') 
                 within group (order by max_dept_nbr) dir
from dir_cte
group by trans_id;
```

Comment: Can you explain what's going on here or give some additional references that you may have used?

Answer (score 0):

An INNER JOIN between the tables can get you close to what you want.
If you really need to get the exact format, you could further `GROUP BY` trans_id, then concatenate the results together for dir

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.trans_id trans_id, t3.dir dir
FROM t2
INNER JOIN t3 ON t2.dept_nbr = t3.dept_nbr
```

This would return
[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer! I really need it in the format I posted, could you please specify how to get it like that? 

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `string_agg` on `distinct` result as follows:

```
Select id, 
       string_agg(dir, '-') within group (order by dept_nbr) as dirs
  From (SELECT DISTINCT t2.trans_id, t3.dir, t2.dept_nbr
          FROM t2 INNER JOIN t3 ON t2.dept_nbr = t3.dept_nbr) t
Group by id
```